# How come portable phone chargers tend to use USBA?

Tags: batteries, usb, battery-charging

How come most portable phone chargers use USBA rather than Micro USB for the output port? Is USBA supposed to be more tolerant? If they use Micro USB for the output (as well), the user could just use a Micro USB-to-Micro USB cable instead, which should be able to handle even 2A, right?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that MicroUSB-B -> USB-A cables are _much_ more common. I've never even seen a dual-ended MicroUSB-B cable.

Comment: Grab one of your double ended micro usb cables and have a look at it... oh wait, you dont have one, well...

Comment: How come they're so rare? A chicken-egg problem?

Comment: USB A & B cables are not supposed to have the same connector on both ends.

Comment: @pjc50 The USB spec does define a Micro-A to Micro-B cable, but I have never seen one "in the wild".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard specifies USBA as the primary charging connector.

USBA makes much sense here as it is widely used on laptops and notebooks.

USBA is mechanically more rugged and reliable than Mini  connectors.

There is a somewhat related discussion on [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/why-was-mini-usb-deprecated-in-favor-of-micro-usb/18559#18559) stack exchange question.