# How to choose which usb connector type is best for Processor working as a device mode?

Tags: usb

Based on my processor specification, USB device mode is supported.USB has different kind of connector based on its host/device/ OTG modes. IF USB-OTG mode supported processor used Micro AB usb connector, Then if my processor only support USB device mode, which is the exact connector should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB is designed to be a connection between a host (PC) and a client (device). For the host, type A connectors are foreseen, and for clients it's type B.

USB OTG means that a device can also act as host, but it does not specify any connectors. As the device is used as client more often than as host, it should have a type B connector.
OTG connections are established via special OTG cables which have type B connectors on both ends.
(By the way, a USB OTG device must also be able to deliver power via USB, as most USB devices are USB powered)

About the question what connector to use:
The standard type B is common, but a bit bulky.
Micro USB is THE standard, as it is used by most mobile phones and power supplies with Micro-B are widely available. This is your best choice if you also plan to power your device by a simple wall wart.
If you think Micro-B is a bit too fragile for your use case, have a look at Mini-USB, which is more rigid than the Micro type. However, this connector isn't used that often any more.

Further more, there is UBS 3.0 and Type C as replacement of Micro-B, but as those are not so common yet, I'd avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, USB devices use one of the various [Type B](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/usb-d-sub-computing-connectors/type-b-usb-connectors/) connectors.

The connector is really specified by whether a device can supply power (Type A), but as the vast majority of devices consume power, they use Type B.

Answer (score 0):

In USB device mode, your device must use one of the [B receptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Connectors).

Type B is comparatively large, Mini-B was [deprecated](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18557/29811), so you should use Micro-B.