# Why aren't PCB mounted male mini USB connector parts common?

Tags: usb, connector, usb-otg

I'm looking to build a USB device that plugs directly into a mini USB OTG port - similar to those USB flash drives that can plug directly into smartphones with OTG-enabled micro USB ports.

I was thinking that the easiest way to build something like that is to have the connector soldered directly onto the PCB board - similar to how existing USB flash drives do it.

[image]

However, I'm not able to find a single supplier that sells PCB mounted male mini USB connectors. All my searches either come up with the female connector or a PCB mounted USB-A connector. The few I have found (from one supplier in China) aren't the USB OTG rounded type (although they would work).

Is there a reason why this is the case? Is it simply because it's not a commonly used part or am I simply not using the right search terms?

Comment: USB OTG adapter? Other than that, I assume it is simply because it is not part of the USB standard, though the [do exist](http://www.ebay.com/itm/170851951385) (google image search "mini usb male smd") just not necessarily from big distributers.

Comment: Considering mini has be depreciated for micro, that's probably why it's harder to find. I'm guessing micro ones are more common considering how many OTG devices are out there

Comment: @TomCarpenter those ones you linked unfortunately don't have the rounded OTG connector that prevents people from plugging it into devices that don't support it. Although, technically they should still work.

Comment: @Passerby that would make sense. Unfortunately the device I'm hoping to build this for doesn't have a microUSB port. I suppose using a deprecated connector in a new design wouldn't make sense anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter too much if you plug an OTG device into a non-OTG port. The non-OTG port will not provide power, so if yours doesn't either nothing will happen. If yours provides power, the non-OTG device will be powered up but given there is no host, nothing will happen - the data lines of both devices will remain in high-z state.

Comment: The other option is to design it with a micro plug (recommended for new designs and pretty easy to get hold of), and then use a micro to mini adapter for your legacy device. That way it also future proofs the design if you want to use it with modern devices.

Comment: USB mini had very limited plug/unplug cycles. Check out this answer http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/why-was-mini-usb-deprecated-in-favor-of-micro-usb

Answer (score 4):

This is because Mini USB has been essentially phased out as depreciated, the newer standard is the USB micro-B bus, which is compatible with 3 times as many sockets as a mini USB.

The mini USB never caught on, not only because of plug, but because of its size. If one were to use a mini USB, the height was very similar to the USB A plug, so those were used instead.

Male SM components were exceptionally uncommon, as there are few uses for devices which have such small hard points. The smaller ports would often break and bend easily compared to the large ports. On top of that, smaller USB form factors were designed specifically for a device that would need a small socket due to space constraints (EG: phone, console controller). If someone needed a Device that plugs into another, there wasn't really any reason that A couldn't be used.

However, There are still many mini A-type USB male SM components out there, I have a sneaking suspicion you're looking on common shopping websites, as opposed to component distributors, the largest known to sell to consumers are [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hirose-Connector/UX40A-MB-5P/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252bykzmHhzPuOAFGD0ndckQzZuU%3D) and [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/UX40-MB-5P/H2955-ND/597531).

Answer (score 1):

What you show in the picture is a standard USB 2.0 connector, not a mini.  Are you looking for a Mini USB Type B?  They are available, but unless you are looking for a "program" volume, you will find it hard to get the attention of any of the manufacturer's.

My company still manufacturers these and you can check out the SMT mounted version at [AVX](http://www.avx.com/products/connectors/specialty/miniusb-5141-series/).  If you have a low volume need, contacting [distribution](http://dilp.netcomponents.com/avx.html) would be the way to go.