# Reading multiple RFID tags at the same time

Tags: arduino, rfid, nfc, iso14443

Hi I've been working on a personal project for which i need to read multiple RFID tags in close proximity, something like 10-20 tags at once, I know RIFD tags can't be actually be read at the same time, fast reading still works for me tho. However I'm having an hard time figuring out if what I want to do is feasible or not.

I've read about ISO14443A tags and that they should work with the RC522 RFID Arduino reader, however it's reading speed is slow.

I have no need for a long reading range, quite small actually, all my tags are disposed separated from each other and in contact with the reader, never stacked.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how could I be able to do what i've set out to do, you're right tho, my question isn't very clear

Comment: They're inside plastic casings

Comment: In my case batches of tagged items are dropped on the reader at the same time and I need to identify them all together before moving to the next batch

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to be completely sure that this would be impossible, but it seems to be very difficult. For what I know, RFID tags just transmit their data as long as their coil receives energy from sensor's coil. They don't have a colision-avoidance system and the tags use the same frequency, there will be a lot of colisions. Did you searched the internet about this? This question was already asked [before](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-RFID-reader-read-multiple-passive-RFID-tags-at-once) and there is mention to a anti-collision protocol.

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=simultaneous+rfid+reader+module&ia=web

Comment: @mguima the anti-collision protocol is part of the ISO14443A standard and that's the direction I'm heading for, however I'm finding little information about the readers

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the link I hadn't find anything about them before. I realize how mine is not a specific question, however I figured that since I have a knowledge gap about the subject it might have qualified as such.

Comment: Perhaps this might help a bit: Can RFID read stacked cards? Asked 2 months ago Active 2 months ago Viewed 86 times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519993/can-rfid-read-stacked-cards/520007#520007

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01 it does give much insight on the components I've researched so fare

Comment: @Riccardo Cecconi, I am glad that my old answers help. Have a great RFID project! Cheers.